# Understanding celery task load balance

Tags: python, celery

I am currently using celery to run my background tasks.

Let's say I want to run these background tasks on weekly basis.

Is it a good idea to throw 20 tasks under one worker?

Each tasks would make about at least 800 web requests.

In the celery docs it says :

```
A single Celery process can process millions of tasks a minute, with sub-millisecond round-trip latency (using RabbitMQ, librabbitmq, and optimized settings).
```

So basically; one task could be for one user; I would need to run at least 50 different tasks; each of them making about 800 web request. I thought; maybe I would need new worker for each tasks; but reviewing the doc it doesn't seem like I need multiple workers for each tasks; instead I can throw all at once; and would be just fine. I don't feel confident about that though; What should I do in my case; if I am making 800 web requests per task; should I need multiple workers? Or should I just do everything under one worker.

Comment: How long does each request take? Is there a time constraint on the task? It sounds like even if those 800 total requests take a day to complete, you should still be good because it only runs once a week. You don't need multiple workers in this case.

Comment: Those requests are made using g requests so it takes about 4 seconds to execute 20 requests.

Comment: That's less than 5 minutes once a week. Do you really need to make that faster?

Comment: Gotcha so my assumption was correct about one worker power. Thank you!